# Error in plotting two spheres under a transformation

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

The following code tries to plot two unit spheres undergoing transformation of their radius and also a translation in z direction:

```
tC = b + a (-1 + b) (-1 + 2 c) - 2 b d;
tI = a + b - a b - 2 a c - 2 b d + 2 a b (d + c e - d e);
gC = a + b - a b; nC = (a (1 - b) c + b d)/(a + b - a b);

tr1 = With[{a = 0.1, b = 0.5, c = 0.1, d = 0.5}, 
   Composition[TranslationTransform[{0, 0, tC}], 
    ScalingTransform[{Sqrt[1 - gC], Sqrt[1 - gC], (1 - gC)}]]];

tr2 = With[{a = 0.1, b = 0.5, c = 0.1, d = 0.5, e = 0.5}, 
   Composition[TranslationTransform[{0, 0, tI}], 
    ScalingTransform[{Sqrt[(1 - a) (1 - b)], 
      Sqrt[(1 - a) (1 - b)], (1 - a) (1 - b)}]]];

RegionPlot3D[
 Evaluate[TransformedRegion[DiscretizeRegion@Sphere[], #] & /@ {tr1, 
    tr2}], PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotLegends -> None, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Black, 17], AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
 PlotStyle -> {FaceForm[Opacity@.01, Blue], 
   FaceForm[Opacity@.001, Cyan], FaceForm[Opacity@.25, Green]}, 
 Mesh -> None, AxesEdge -> Automatic, Ticks -> None, ImageSize -> 300]
```

Kindly help to resolve what's going wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Block` instead of `With` in your definition of `tr1` and `tr2`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]